# Htaccess code is creating never ending redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following in my htaccess file and my site uses SSL.
If I only keep part 1, the website works.
Else if I add Part 2 as well, the site does not open; continuous redirection takes place. I want to know what am I doing incorrect. This will help me resolve the issue.
mydomainname.com is for example my website domain name.
Please advice.

```
# Part 1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomainname.com/$1 [R,L]
#</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Part 2

# Begin Disable hotlinking and leeching
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomainname.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?feeds2.feedburner.com/mydomainname [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]
# End Disable hotlinking and leeching

<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=84600, public"
</filesMatch>

## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES HEADER CACHING ##

Redirect 301 /programs/ /programs/
Redirect 301 /webinar/ /media/

# BEGIN EWWWIO

# END EWWWIO
```

Comment: Why are you redirecting the `/programs/` uri to itself? `Redirect 301 /programs/ /programs/`

Comment: Assuming @starkeen's correct, either answer your own question saying so, or delete it altogether.